# How to use getRandom on Raspberry pi

Tags: c, linux, gcc, raspberry-pi

How to use getrandom linux syscall on raspberry pi? GCC can't find macro "SYS_getrandom" nor function it self. I am missing some library? Should I use old way?

Comment: What do you mean by *old way*?

Comment: What kernel are you running?

Comment: Unclear. What happens when you do ? Please edit question and add some details.

Answer (score 3):

To use `getrandom()` you have to make sure that:

- You kernel version is `3.17` or newer
- You've included `linux/random.h` (or `sys/syscall.h` if you're using `syscall`)
- Mentioned headers define `getrandom()` and `SYS_getrandom`

If your kernel is old, consider upgrading it. If it's fine, but `getrandom()` and `SYS_getrandom` are not defined, consider upgrading `glibc`.

And if upgrading is not an option, then you're left with `rand()`ing in a loop, reading from `/dev/random`, or doing something else that strikes your fancy.